# Synchronize KMail and KOrganizer with my Google data

Tags: kde, kmail

Is there a way to synchronize KMail and KOrganizer with my Google data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this [blog post](http://blog.trumpton.org.uk/2010/02/kontact-gmail-sync-with-akonadi.html)? I think it may answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. The third para is scary, and makes me not want to do it.

Comment: Please do not post an answer with just a link. Post real content in your answer, so that it is still a meaningful answer if the reader cannot or does not want to follow the link. Keep the link for further information. See [How to answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).